# SpringEL engine vs Thymeleaf engine of evaluating boolean literals

Tags: java, thymeleaf

In [Thymeleaf Documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#boolean-literals) it is said that it's possible to evaluate `boolean` literals using **Thymeleaf itself** (when `== false` is written outside the braces), so that Thymeleaf takes care of it:

```
<div th:if="${user.isAdmin()} == false"> ...
```

as well as write it inside the braces, so that it would be responsibility of the **SpringEL engine**:

```
<div th:if="${user.isAdmin() == false}"> ...
```

*Which way is preferable, has it really any performance or readability difference? What is the best practice of using it?*

Answer (score 0):

I think is just readability difference..